# Add "Excerpt" in "Quick edit"

Tags: excerpt, quick-edit

I have many posts in which I want to edit the excerpt. But instead of having to got to the edit page, I would want to do it with the "Quick Edit" feature.

How can I add the excerpt in the Quick Edit ?

PS: I know a plugin exists for that, but I have a custom plugin for my website, so it would be cool if I can add this in it.

EDIT: I don't want to use the plugin because I am not really fan of using plugins when there's a possibility to easily add code somewhere to do what I want to do. 
Also the plugin "Custom Bulk/Quick Edit" I was talking have many features I won't use.

Comment: Please describe your development problem more precise. What plugin is there, how does it solve what you want to do, and what stops you from using that plugin / solving it the same way?

Comment: Just for your information. Themes are for visual display, plugins are for functional performance. There is no (NO) difference between running a plugin or `functions.php`.

Answer (score -1):

I too am looking for this option / feature. I came across [this guys](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/quick-edit-tutorial.html) explanation which I believe answers most of the question. I am in the process of implementing this so I cannot say how accurate it is being a wordpress noob (not php!), I do realise this is for a custom box but you could populate the column field using the `the_excerpt()` fn or from the $post object - etc.

So it seems, to have the option we want available in the quick edit section, we need to add it as a "custom" column in the post / page list view first.

```
/*
 * New columns
 */
add_filter('manage_post_posts_columns', 'misha_featured_columns');
// the above hook will add columns only for default 'post' post type, for CPT:
// manage_{POST TYPE NAME}_posts_columns
function misha_price_and_featured_columns( $column_array ) {
    $column_array['featured'] = 'Featured product';
    return $column_array;
}

/*
 * Populate our new columns with data
 */
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'misha_populate_column', 10, 2);
function misha_populate_column( $column_name, $id ) {
    switch( $column_name ) :

        case 'featured': {
            if( get_post_meta($id,'product_featured',true) == 'on') 
                echo 'Yes';
            break;
        }
    endswitch;

}
```

Then we can add it to the quick edit section.

```
/*
 * quick_edit_custom_box allows to add HTML in Quick Edit
 * Please note: it files for EACH column, so it is similar to manage_posts_custom_column
 */
add_action('quick_edit_custom_box',  'misha_quick_edit_fields', 10, 2);

function misha_quick_edit_fields( $column_name, $post_type ) {

    switch( $column_name ) :

        case 'featured': {

            echo '<fieldset><label class="alignleft">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="featured">
                    <span class="checkbox-title">Featured product</span>
                </label></fieldset>';

            break;

        }

    endswitch;

}
```

We also need some code to hook into save post to allow for updating the meta data.

```
/*
 * Quick Edit Save
 */
add_action( 'save_post', 'misha_quick_edit_save' );

function misha_quick_edit_save( $post_id ){

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['misha_nonce'], 'misha_q_edit_nonce' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['featured'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_featured', 'on' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_featured', '' );
    }

}
```

Lastly some JavaScript, he uses jQuery, is required to populate the fields data once the page is loaded. This he places in a separate file and loads with wp_enqueue:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_enqueue_quick_edit_population' );
function misha_enqueue_quick_edit_population( $pagehook ) {

    // do nothing if we are not on the target pages
    if ( 'edit.php' != $pagehook ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'populatequickedit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/populate.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

}
```

JavaScript file:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var wp_inline_edit_function = inlineEditPost.edit;

    inlineEditPost.edit = function( post_id ) {

        wp_inline_edit_function.apply( this, arguments );

        var id = 0;
        if ( typeof( post_id ) == 'object' ) { // if it is object, get the ID number
            id = parseInt( this.getId( post_id ) );
        }

        if ( id > 0 ) {

            // add rows to variables
            var specific_post_edit_row = $( '#edit-' + id ),
                specific_post_row = $( '#post-' + id ),
                featured_product = false; // let's say by default checkbox is unchecked

            if( $( '.column-featured', specific_post_row ).text() == 'Yes' ) featured_product = true;

            $( ':input[name="featured"]', specific_post_edit_row ).prop('checked', featured_product );
        }
    }
});
```

I've copy, pasted & edited his raw code for reference, the tutorial at the site has comments within in the code explaining its use etc. I don't know this person just came across this post and theirs whilst googling.

Finally one thing I believe may need pointing out is that the save_post hook could interfere with any hooks you already have for save_post and I am unsure if quick edit save_post would recognise the excerpt field as standard or would need the hook above?!